# Error: 404 Category not found error with custom PHP script

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, ajax

For some time now I have been working with Joomla, and now I am working with a version 3.1.5.  I often make my own PHP scripts to use for AJAX callbacks and other things.  I put them in a folder called `scripts` which isn't part of the normal Joomla installation.

Because of this I have to use some configuration code to get the scripts to work well when accessing them from Joomla.  I use this code:

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

/* Create the Application */
$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
```

Recently I am trying to call this script for AJAX and I am getting this following error:

> 404 (Category not found)

The only reason I can think of for this is that Joomla things that the user doesn't have privileges to read the script because of some reason to do with a category?  I am not sure, and I am looking for some help.  I have created any categories for this Joomla installation and I don't use them.

Comment: Have you moved your custom PHP file or the location of your Joomla site to a different folder?

Comment: no, the AJAX call still works from another page on the same site, with the same path to this script.

Comment: What all data are you submitting to this page with the AJAX? Sounds like you likely have an input variable set that joomla is trying to process by default.

Comment: I've got the same problem with 100% external files, so they don't contain any Joomla file includes.
EDIT: Try to delete the .htaccess, and see what happens. Actually, my file had an internal server error...

Comment: What does the AJAX URL look like? What params are you sending?

Comment: Thanks ALL for the help here.  It ended up being a strange problem with our update from Joomla 3.1.5 to 3.3.0.  After the update there were a lot of system errors in the JS and JQuery that I could see.  And it was sending the AJAX requests to faulty addresses.  That is why it happened all-of-a-sudden.  We rolled back the version and everything is fine again!

Answer (score 2):

When you call **independent PHP scripts** for AJAX callbacks, you have to check how they live along the regular Joomla! site.

In a common Apache-Joomla setup, first .htaccess applies several rules to define security restrictions, SEF processing, etc. After that, index.php takes control, initializes the CMS, routes the call to the right component, and finally generate the output.

In your case, it seems *Apache is delegating the call to com_content component, instead of calling your script*.

Answer (score 0):

I guys. In my case, I was having this because the 'task' was not being passed to the page. I had a hidden form field that had

`<input type="hidden" name="jform[task]" value="myCustomTask">`

instead of

`<input type="hidden" name="task" value="myCustomTask">`

That was mainly because I had the task in the a form's XML file.